# Stop animation of sceneView.pointOfView

Tags: swift, scenekit

This is my Code to animate sceneView.pointOfView:

```
let action = SCNAction.run {_ in
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = duration
    SCNTransaction.animationTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: easing)
    
    SCNTransaction.completionBlock = {
        completion?()
    }
    
    self.setNewPosition(pointOfView: pointOfView)
    SCNTransaction.commit()
}

sceneView.pointOfView?.runAction(action)
```

How can I stop this animation when I want before it finishes? I tried using `sceneView.pointOfView?.removeAllActions()`, but it doesn't work

Comment: You can stop an ongoing SCNTransaction only by setting its animated properties to their destinated End-Values. Doing removeAllActions will not help in this case, because it's a running SCNTransaction. If it is a real SCNAction like moveTo or moveBy you can stop it at any time by calling removeAllActions()

Comment: "You can stop an ongoing SCNTransaction only by setting its animated properties to their destinated End-Values" Can you provide an example? I tried, but it doesn't work.